# Linux symbolic links how to make target file in currently directory an automatic absolute path?

Tags: bash

Here is the story:

```
cd ~
mkdir bin
export PATH=$PATH:bin
mkdir -p projects
cd projects
echo 'hello world' > hello.sh
chmod +x hello.sh
ln -s hello.sh ~/bin/hello
hello
```

output:

```
-bash: hello: command not found
```

How I changed it:

```
ln -s hello.sh ~/bin
hello.sh
```

The output is more weird:

```
-bash: /home/qht/bin/hello.sh: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

I ls it to see what happened:

```
ls -l ~/bin/hello.sh
/home/qht/bin/hello.sh -> hello.sh
```

I figure it out, hello.sh reference itself. And hello before reference hello.sh which doesn't exist.

I fix it by:

```
ln -sf $PWD/hello.sh ~/bin/hello
ls ~/bin/hello
/home/qht/bin/hello -> /home/qht/projects/hello.sh
```

and it works, I also **man ln** to see if there is a convenient option to do that, this is what I found:

```
ln -sfr hello.sh ~/bin/hello
ls -l ~/bin/hello
/home/qht/bin/hello -> ../projects/hello.sh
```

And it works, the -r option did the work.

But I'm curious, **if ln -r can automatically write the relative path data into symbolic links, Why doesn't there an option maybe -a to do the absolute path work.**

Or, is relative path for links is more practical than absolute path?

Comment: Your PATH declaration is missing ~/.  It should be PATH=$PATH:~/bin.  Having just bin means the bin sub-directory of the current directory.  Could be a nasty security hole.

Comment: I did the export in my home directory, echo $PATH show that it's :/home/qht/bin

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd ~
mkdir bin
export PATH=$PATH:~/bin                 # Need absolute path to bin
mkdir -p projects
cd projects
echo 'echo "hello world"' > hello.sh    # If the script is just hello world
                                        # this will become an infinite loop
chmod +x hello.sh
ln -s "$PWD/hello.sh" ~/bin/hello       # the symbolic link in this case
                                        # needs to be a absolute path
hello
```

Comment: As you see,  i did the same thing(not necessary the ~/bin, already in ~). My question is, is there a ln option to automatically do that . I think maybe there is not.

Comment: Not that I am aware of